# Django oauth2 Facebook autentication

Tags: python, django

Ao tentar incluir a autorização de login pelo facebook no meu site, segui os passos dados em documentações do Django e semelhantes.

E fazendo passo a passo, incluindo o app no settings

```
"allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook",
```

Incluindo o app no sistema de admin e configurando corretamente o app do facebook no site,
o próximo passo foi incluir a configuração no html corretamente :

```
{% load socialaccount %}
{% providers_media_js %}
<button><a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="oauth2" %}">Login com Facebook</a></button>
</div>
```

Ao entrar na url de login no site, no entanto, o erro :

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /accounts/login/
No module named 'path'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/
Django Version: 3.1.3
Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
No module named 'path'
```

Esse erro aparentemente permanece mesmo tirando da settings, onde depois de retira-lo é somente :

```
KeyError at /accounts/login/
'facebook'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/
Django Version: 3.1.3
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'facebook'
```

Comment: você precisa de uma modulo extra!

Comment: Ok ... Como e onde fazer esse modulo extra /

Answer (score 0):

Autentificação usando mídias sociais necessita de um modulo extra no projeto.
O servidor não encontrou um intermediário que faça isso e devido a falta retorno esse aviso.

Indico o social-auth-app-django, para fazer essa autentificação,não apenas para rede social mencionada mais para quais quer outra.

sua configuração é bem explicada na pagina oficial  [pagina](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration/django.html#authentication-backends)

após concluir a instalação: pip install social-auth-app-django

Sera necessário registrar no apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'social_django',
    ...
)
```

Na página oficial, "Há um processador de contexto que adicionará back-ends e dados de associações ao contexto do modelo:":
isso quer dizer que através do social_django sera adicionado nos templates contexto de autentificação como nome foto

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',#<==1
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',#<==2
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

especificar autentificação pela rede social e não mais pelo django

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
   ]
```

Configurações do app desenvolvedor do facebook, ao utilizar esse recurso não sera recriado uma nova autentificação para o usuario após fazer logout e iniciar novamente o login

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = 'sua chave'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'codigo'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email', 'user_link'] #parametros a extrair
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
    'fields': 'id, name, email, picture.type(large), link'
}
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_EXTRA_DATA = [
    ('name', 'name'),
    ('email', 'email'),
    ('picture', 'picture'),
    ('link', 'profile_url'),
]
```

view pagina de explanação do login:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class LoginView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'login.html'
```

na url da app:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views # autenticação de views

from .views import  LoginView# campos de login 

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),# logout
    path('social-auth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')), # api extra
 
]
```

no  html autentificação usando rede social e não o padrão django:

```
   <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}">rede social</a>
        </button>
          iniciar
        <button>
```

Comment: Entendi, vou implementar. Mas uma duvida, eu ja havia feito com o social.account.providers do django allauth e inclui o github como um dos provedores, e estava funcionando normalmente. É necessário retirar a settings atuais poderia permanecer com o mesmo autorizador e só incluir esse novo módulo ?

Comment: não a problemas tbm,

Comment: Posso só incluir essa nova autorização então certo ?

Comment: Se você usou outro meio de auth e utilizar essa junto não dara erro.

Comment: Aparentemente o erro continua 
```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/
'social' is not a registered namespace
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/
```

Comment: esse é o  roteamento.